# Using eval to read an encrypted file

Tags: php, eval, mcrypt

I have a php file which was encrypted using `mcrypt` and now we need to decrypt it.

Here is the decryption:

```
abstract class Encryption_Abstract {
    const CYPHER = 'blowfish';
    const MODE = 'cfb';
    protected $key;
    public
    function __construct($key) {
        $this->key = $key;
    }
    public function encrypt($plaintext) {
        return $plaintext;
    }
    public function decrypt($crypttext) {
        return $crypttext;
    }
}
//decryptor
class Decryption extends Encryption_Abstract {
    function decrypt($crypttext) {
        $plaintext = '';
        $td = mcrypt_module_open(self::CYPHER, '', self::MODE, '');
        $ivsize = mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size($td);
        $iv = substr($crypttext, 0, $ivsize);
        $crypttext = substr($crypttext, $ivsize);
        if ($iv) {
            mcrypt_generic_init($td, $this - > key, $iv);
            $plaintext = mdecrypt_generic($td, $crypttext);
        }
        return $plaintext;
    }
}
```

Now this is how we instantiate it and then use it:

```
$enc = new Decryption(KEYS::PROD);  //KEYS::PROD is the decryption key
eval($enc->decrypt(file_get_contents("key_file.txt"))); //<--
```

Is there any way to **not** use `eval`? or is it my only option?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's a PHP file and you need to execute it, you can pipe it to a `php` cli.. but it would be the same. But how would you want to execute a PHP file without executing it?:)

Comment: @Gabi, so in conclusion, i would have to use `eval()`?

Comment: @Neal you don't _have to_, but other solutions have similar security problems.

Comment: @Gabi, there really shouldnt be an issue if we encrypted the file? the only reason why we did that is so our client won't be able to fiddle with it

Comment: @Neal of course it's no problem if the code belongs to you and you trust it.

Comment: @Gabi, ok I (and we) do and should trust it. so basically this is doing a fake `include` of the php file except with `eval` -- which should be ok

Comment: Yes, as Gabi has said, as long as the code belongs to you and you trust it, go ahead and use the `eval()`. Though, if the client's server has the encryption key in order to programmatically decrypt and eval the file, couldn't they also find that and use it to fiddle with the code anyway?

Answer (score 1):

You could store decrypted contents in temporary file, include it and delete after that:

```
$contents = $enc->decrypt(file_get_contents("key_file.txt"));

$tmpFile = tempnam('/tmp', 'decrypted.');
file_put_contents($tmpFile, $contents);

include $tmpFile;

unlink($tmpFile);
```

Comment: the problem with that is that there is a minute change that they could see what the encrypted file contains (which we don't really want)

Comment: @Neal either way, your parent script contains the method required to decrypt the file (keys + algorithm) so you've essentially got zero security anyways.

Comment: @MarcB the file that this code is in is obfuscated (the client cannot read it at all)